# Why style changes apply so late

Tags: css, codeigniter, caching, styles

I'm developing a website with Codeigniter.

but i don't know why changes applied so late when i change the CSS or create a new class.

I didn't enable any things about cache.

it maybe take around one or more than one hour.

here in header file i loaded the css file
      
      
      
      
      Welcome to my site

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>layout/style-<?php echo      $this->session->userdata('lang'); ?>.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: changes applied so late means ? can you explain a bit more clearly ?

Comment: i mean for example when i change a font family and save it in css file the changes will appear on site after long time, maybe one hour!

Comment: Can you post some code like the source with the **`<head></head>`** from where you load the css file ?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Welcome to my site</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>layout/style-<?php echo $this->session->userdata('lang'); ?>.css" type="text/css">

Comment: Can change like this and check again ? to check the cache is the problem.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>layout/style-<?php echo $this->session->userdata('lang'); ?>.css?<?php echo time() ?>" type="text/css">`

Comment: where can i see the result of echo time()? i didnt catch your mean!

Comment: It will add a timestamp at the end of the css url whic make the url unique each time you load. I have asked you to do this to check if the cache is the problem. got it ?

Comment: Better use versioning on the css file name. When ever something changed increase the version number of the file. If you add timestamp, unnecessarily your css file loaded by browser even if there are no changes done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach solves the issue. Here we are appending the file modified time after the filename. So the file is cached when it is not modified and when file is changed timestamp change and the file is loaded again by browser.

Set the relative path correctly to the style sheet to filemtime function.

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>layout/style-<?php echo $this->session->userdata('lang'); ?>.css?<?php echo filemtime('relative-path/' . "layout/style-" . $this->session->userdata('lang') . ".css"); ?>" type="text/css">
```